# Adding custom field jQuery Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables to populate my data. I am using the server side method which I need coz I am fetching hundred thousand records. However I don't know how to add a custom field. For example

```
|Action|
________
http://localhost/qms/public/customer/1/edit
```

Which the `1` should be the ID

Because on the datatables, you only declaring column tables that you need so I don't know how to add a custom one.

I currently have this:

[image]

I need to put action column to edit those customers. I am using Laravel 5.1

HTML View:

```
<table id="CustomerList" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7"> <center>Customer Information<center></th>
            <!-- <th colspan="2"> <center>Actions<center></th> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Postcode</th>
        <!--     <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th> -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;
        $('#CustomerList').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "api/customer/all",
            "paging" : true,
            "searching" : true,
            "ordering" :  true,
        } );
        var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( $('#CustomerList').DataTable() );
        $( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function apiGetCustomers()
{
    /*=================================================================*/
    /*
     * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and PostgreSQL
     * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
     * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
     */

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * Easy set variables
     */

    /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
     * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
     */
    $aColumns = array('id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'gender', 'phone_num', 'country', 'postcode' );

    /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
    $sIndexColumn = "phone_num";

    /* DB table to use */
    $sTable = "customers";

    /* Database connection information */
    $gaSql['user']       = "postgres";
    $gaSql['password']   = "postgres";
    $gaSql['db']         = "qms";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";



    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
     * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
     * no need to edit below this line
     */

    /*
     * DB connection
     */
    $gaSql['link'] = pg_connect(
        " host=".$gaSql['server'].
        " dbname=".$gaSql['db'].
        " user=".$gaSql['user'].
        " password=".$gaSql['password']
    ) or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


    /*
     * Paging
     */
    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] )." OFFSET ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] );
    }


    /*
     * Ordering
     */
    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc').", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    /*
     * Filtering
     * NOTE This assumes that the field that is being searched on is a string typed field (ie. one
     * on which ILIKE can be used). Boolean fields etc will need a modification here.
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                if($aColumns[$i] != 'id') // Exclude ID for filtering
                {
                    $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." ILIKE '%".pg_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
                }
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ")";
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." ILIKE '%".pg_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }


    $sQuery = "
        SELECT ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
        FROM   $sTable
        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";

    $rResult = pg_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ) or die(pg_last_error());

    $sQuery = "
        SELECT $sIndexColumn
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = pg_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ) or die(pg_last_error());
    $iTotal = pg_num_rows($rResultTotal);
    pg_free_result( $rResultTotal );

    if ( $sWhere != "" )
    {
        $sQuery = "
            SELECT $sIndexColumn
            FROM   $sTable
            $sWhere
        ";
        $rResultFilterTotal = pg_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ) or die(pg_last_error());
        $iFilteredTotal = pg_num_rows($rResultFilterTotal);
        pg_free_result( $rResultFilterTotal );
    }
    else
    {
        $iFilteredTotal = $iTotal;
    }

    /*
     * Output
     */
    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = pg_fetch_array($rResult, null, PGSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );

    // Free resultset
    pg_free_result( $rResult );

    // Closing connection
    pg_close( $gaSql['link'] );


}
```

Comment: **TIP**: Remove your username and password for the database from the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

- In HTML add one column in the table header for **Action**.
- In DataTables initialization options add [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to target that 8<sup>th</sup> column (`"targets": 7`, zero-based index) and use [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to produce content for that column.

  In the [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function, you can use `row` variable to access the data for the row. Since you're returning array of arrays in your PHP script, you can access your ID by using `row[0]` (1<sup>st</sup> column, zero-based index).

  ```
  var table = $('#CustomerList').DataTable( {
     "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": "api/customer/all"
     "columnDefs": [
          { 
              "targets": 7,
              "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                 return '<a href="/qms/public/customer/' + row[0] + '/edit">Edit</a>';  
              }
          }            
      ]        
  });
  ```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lhd6wgc/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add headers for the custom fields, as you have above `<th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th>`
2. Use [**column rendering**](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) to add the content of the custom fields. Since you are using an "array of arrays" as datasource, you must do it this way :

small demonstration -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pqgynvys/**

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data : data.data,
    columns : [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
       { render : function() {
             return '<button>edit</button>'
         }
       }, 
       { render : function() {
             return '<button>delete</button>'
         }
       } 
  ]   
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll update this one coz @Gyrocode.com answers first and I find it much simpler. Thanks though!